# Parsing robot.txt using java and identify whether an url is allowed

Tags: java, web-scraping, jsoup, crawler4j

I am currently using jsoup in a application to parse and analyses web pages.But I want to make sure that I am adhere to the robot.txt rules and only visit pages which are allowed.

I am pretty sure that jsoup is not made for this and it's all about web scraping and parsing.
So I planned to have function/module which should read the robot.txt of the domain/site and identify whether the url I am going to visit is allowed or not.

I did some research and found the followings.But it I am not sure about these so it would be great if one did same kind of project where robot.txt parsing involved please share your thoughts and ideas.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/jrobotx/

https://code.google.com/p/crawler-commons/

http://code.google.com/p/crowl/source/browse/trunk/Crow/src/org/crow/base/Robotstxt.java?r=12

Comment: What's the question exactly? And parsing robot.txt seems a bit out of scope for Jsoup. Jsoup is for parsing webpages as you say so yourself.

Comment: Thanks,Ya, I am using jsoup for parsing pages... but the requirement is to parse the urls which are only allowed(not restricted) in robots.txt.. and for this validation seems JSoup is not the best or not capable. So what I need to know is how can I achieve this validation on robots.txt before doing the actual parsing.

Comment: Ok this is nice. I was searching to work on a little project using jsoup so I might do it myself.

Comment: @alkis did you wind up coming up with anything?

Answer (score 7):

A late answer just in case you - or someone else - are still looking for a way to do this. I am using https://code.google.com/p/crawler-commons/ in version 0.2 and it seems to work well. Here is a simplified example from the code I use:

```
String USER_AGENT = "WhateverBot";
String url = "http://www.....com/";
URL urlObj = new URL(url);
String hostId = urlObj.getProtocol() + "://" + urlObj.getHost()
                + (urlObj.getPort() > -1 ? ":" + urlObj.getPort() : "");
Map<String, BaseRobotRules> robotsTxtRules = new HashMap<String, BaseRobotRules>();
BaseRobotRules rules = robotsTxtRules.get(hostId);
if (rules == null) {
    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(hostId + "/robots.txt");
    HttpContext context = new BasicHttpContext();
    HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httpget, context);
    if (response.getStatusLine() != null && response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 404) {
        rules = new SimpleRobotRules(RobotRulesMode.ALLOW_ALL);
        // consume entity to deallocate connection
        EntityUtils.consumeQuietly(response.getEntity());
    } else {
        BufferedHttpEntity entity = new BufferedHttpEntity(response.getEntity());
        SimpleRobotRulesParser robotParser = new SimpleRobotRulesParser();
        rules = robotParser.parseContent(hostId, IOUtils.toByteArray(entity.getContent()),
                "text/plain", USER_AGENT);
    }
    robotsTxtRules.put(hostId, rules);
}
boolean urlAllowed = rules.isAllowed(url);
```

Obviously this is not related to Jsoup in any way, it just checks whether a given URL is allowed to be crawled for a certain USER_AGENT. For fetching the robots.txt I use the Apache HttpClient in version 4.2.1, but this could be replaced by java.net stuff as well.

Please note that this code only checks for allowance or disallowance and does not consider other robots.txt features like "Crawl-delay". But as the crawler-commons provide this feature as well, it can be easily added to the code above.

Answer (score 2):

The above didn't work for me. I took managed to put this together. First time I'm doing Java in 4 years, so I'm sure this can be improved.

```
public static boolean robotSafe(URL url) 
{
    String strHost = url.getHost();

    String strRobot = "http://" + strHost + "/robots.txt";
    URL urlRobot;
    try { urlRobot = new URL(strRobot);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        // something weird is happening, so don't trust it
        return false;
    }

    String strCommands;
    try 
    {
        InputStream urlRobotStream = urlRobot.openStream();
        byte b[] = new byte[1000];
        int numRead = urlRobotStream.read(b);
        strCommands = new String(b, 0, numRead);
        while (numRead != -1) {
            numRead = urlRobotStream.read(b);
            if (numRead != -1) 
            {
                    String newCommands = new String(b, 0, numRead);
                    strCommands += newCommands;
            }
        }
       urlRobotStream.close();
    } 
    catch (IOException e) 
    {
        return true; // if there is no robots.txt file, it is OK to search
    }

    if (strCommands.contains(DISALLOW)) // if there are no "disallow" values, then they are not blocking anything.
    {
        String[] split = strCommands.split("\n");
        ArrayList<RobotRule> robotRules = new ArrayList<>();
        String mostRecentUserAgent = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < split.length; i++) 
        {
            String line = split[i].trim();
            if (line.toLowerCase().startsWith("user-agent")) 
            {
                int start = line.indexOf(":") + 1;
                int end   = line.length();
                mostRecentUserAgent = line.substring(start, end).trim();
            }
            else if (line.startsWith(DISALLOW)) {
                if (mostRecentUserAgent != null) {
                    RobotRule r = new RobotRule();
                    r.userAgent = mostRecentUserAgent;
                    int start = line.indexOf(":") + 1;
                    int end   = line.length();
                    r.rule = line.substring(start, end).trim();
                    robotRules.add(r);
                }
            }
        }

        for (RobotRule robotRule : robotRules)
        {
            String path = url.getPath();
            if (robotRule.rule.length() == 0) return true; // allows everything if BLANK
            if (robotRule.rule == "/") return false;       // allows nothing if /

            if (robotRule.rule.length() <= path.length())
            { 
                String pathCompare = path.substring(0, robotRule.rule.length());
                if (pathCompare.equals(robotRule.rule)) return false;
            }
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

And you will need the helper class:

```
/**
 *
 * @author Namhost.com
 */
public class RobotRule 
{
    public String userAgent;
    public String rule;

    RobotRule() {

    }

    @Override public String toString() 
    {
        StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
        String NEW_LINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
        result.append(this.getClass().getName() + " Object {" + NEW_LINE);
        result.append("   userAgent: " + this.userAgent + NEW_LINE);
        result.append("   rule: " + this.rule + NEW_LINE);
        result.append("}");
        return result.toString();
    }    
}
```

Comment: Does this support wildcard matching?

Comment: `readLine()` should be used for a text file consisting of lines, not reading character by character. I doubt this code really works correctly.